# CasperJS isn't doing the same request as normal browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have made some script in CasperJs to login to page, open specific page and get content of it.
I'm opening desired page with content to scrap with `casper.thenOpen` and it shows different content on casperjs and different on my browser. I have setted up useragent from my browser and still no effects. Here are request and response headers from casperjs:
http://screenshot.sh/m7QeJGUbqK5Kg
And here from my browser:
http://screenshot.sh/n8j3Gf9QkuXxm
I don't know why the results are different on browser and casperjs. I don't know why there is no cookie in request header in casperjs but i'm sure that it's logged in because previusly in code i can see code allowed only for logged users.

Thanks in advance for any help

Code:

```
casper.thenOpen('website.com', function() { 
                    this.echo("start");
                    this.echo(this.fetchText('html'), "INFO");
                    casper.then(function () {
                        var json;
                        var start;
                        var end;
                        function checkReload()
                        {
                            json = JSON.parse(this.fetchText('html'));
                            if(json.msg.indexOf('desiredtext') === 0) { 

                                this.echo("good", 'PARAMETER');
                                return; 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.echo('bad news: ' + json.msg, 'COMMENT');
                            }
                            casper.thenOpen('website.com');
                            this.echo(this.fetchText('html'));
                            this.wait(1, checkReload); 
                        }
                        this.then(checkReload);
                    });
                });
```

But problem isn't in code(I also tried to put request headers from browser to casper but this didn't work)

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @jcaron added, if you can try heling me it will be great news

Comment: There's nothing in you code doing any kind of log in... The response you get is a redirect, which could mean either that it's just missing some cookies (some sites redirect you multiple times for this for various reasons), or that's it missing login cookies (in which case it will redirect you to a login page). You need to follow those redirects, and see what the final pages says.